# pc goes to sleep but imediatly restart. os independant

Tags: drivers, suspend, standby

My PC refuses to go into sleep mode under any operating system (Windows 10 22H2, Linux Mint 21.3, Ubuntu 23.10). Even with the proprietary AMD drivers installed, it consistently does the same thing – it goes into sleep mode but immediately restarts and exits sleep mode.

Here is my configuration:

**Motherboard**: Aorus B550M Aorus Elite whit last bios update (18c)
**CPU**: AMD Ryzen 3 3100 
**GPU**: MSI AMD RX 570

Sorry, my English is poor. I'm French

Comment: Perhaps this might help you to find the reason: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132115/how-to-find-reason-a-notebook-wakes-up

Comment: Note I have closed this because this is a Hardware Problem and not an Ubuntu issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you you right.

Yes I have resolved the problem it was a motherboard bios version problem with primary nvme SSD Its not working over bios version 12

My bios was in 18c I have downgraded it to 10 and it works

Answer (score 1):

Since you write that it affects all operating systems, that sounds like a setting in your BIOS is responsible.

Check the "ACPI" settings. It might also be named something like "After power loss go to..." where you can select to reboot, to power down, or to go to the previous state.